PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented when adding more columns
I am getting this warning when inserting new columns in a dataframe that are shifted copies of existing columns. How can I rewrite this code so as to avoid the warning? One solution I found was copying the whole dataframe after every insertion, but that seems inefficient.
data = {str(i):[pow(k, i) for k in range(1000)] for i in range(1, 6)}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
for col in df.columns:
    for offset in range(1, 30):
        df[f'{col}-{offset}'] = df[col].shift(offset)
        # df = df.copy() # solved the problem, but likely not best solution


You can collect the new columns to a list and then use pd.concat.
columns = []
names = []
for col in df.columns:
    for offset in range(1, 30):
        names.append(f'{col}-{offset}')
        columns.append(df[col].shift(offset))

pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(names, columns)))], axis=1)


You could use columns.append(df[col].shift(offset).rename(f'{col}-{offset}')) to have the correct names ;)

I just remap it using dict(zip(...))

You can shift the whole DataFrame at once and concat the output:
out = df.join(pd.concat({offset: df.shift(offset) for offset in range(1, 30)}, axis=1)
                .sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
                .pipe(lambda d: d.set_axis(d.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[1]}-{x[0]}'), axis=1))
             )

Output (example with smaller dimensions):
   1   2    3     4      5  1-1  1-2  1-3  1-4  1-5  1-6  1-7  1-8  1-9   2-1   2-2   2-3   2-4   2-5  2-6  2-7  2-8  2-9    3-1    3-2    3-3    3-4   3-5   3-6  3-7  3-8  3-9     4-1     4-2     4-3    4-4    4-5   4-6   4-7  4-8  4-9      5-1      5-2     5-3     5-4     5-5    5-6   5-7  5-8  5-9
0  0   0    0     0      0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
1  1   1    1     1      1  0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   0.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    0.0    NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN     0.0     NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN      0.0      NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
2  2   4    8    16     32  1.0  0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   1.0   0.0   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    1.0    0.0    NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN     1.0     0.0     NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN      1.0      0.0     NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
3  3   9   27    81    243  2.0  1.0  0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   4.0   1.0   0.0   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    8.0    1.0    0.0    NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    16.0     1.0     0.0    NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN     32.0      1.0     0.0     NaN     NaN    NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
4  4  16   64   256   1024  3.0  2.0  1.0  0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   9.0   4.0   1.0   0.0   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   27.0    8.0    1.0    0.0   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    81.0    16.0     1.0    0.0    NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN    243.0     32.0     1.0     0.0     NaN    NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
5  5  25  125   625   3125  4.0  3.0  2.0  1.0  0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  16.0   9.0   4.0   1.0   0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   64.0   27.0    8.0    1.0   0.0   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   256.0    81.0    16.0    1.0    0.0   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN   1024.0    243.0    32.0     1.0     0.0    NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
6  6  36  216  1296   7776  5.0  4.0  3.0  2.0  1.0  0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  25.0  16.0   9.0   4.0   1.0  0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  125.0   64.0   27.0    8.0   1.0   0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN   625.0   256.0    81.0   16.0    1.0   0.0   NaN  NaN  NaN   3125.0   1024.0   243.0    32.0     1.0    0.0   NaN  NaN  NaN
7  7  49  343  2401  16807  6.0  5.0  4.0  3.0  2.0  1.0  0.0  NaN  NaN  36.0  25.0  16.0   9.0   4.0  1.0  0.0  NaN  NaN  216.0  125.0   64.0   27.0   8.0   1.0  0.0  NaN  NaN  1296.0   625.0   256.0   81.0   16.0   1.0   0.0  NaN  NaN   7776.0   3125.0  1024.0   243.0    32.0    1.0   0.0  NaN  NaN
8  8  64  512  4096  32768  7.0  6.0  5.0  4.0  3.0  2.0  1.0  0.0  NaN  49.0  36.0  25.0  16.0   9.0  4.0  1.0  0.0  NaN  343.0  216.0  125.0   64.0  27.0   8.0  1.0  0.0  NaN  2401.0  1296.0   625.0  256.0   81.0  16.0   1.0  0.0  NaN  16807.0   7776.0  3125.0  1024.0   243.0   32.0   1.0  0.0  NaN
9  9  81  729  6561  59049  8.0  7.0  6.0  5.0  4.0  3.0  2.0  1.0  0.0  64.0  49.0  36.0  25.0  16.0  9.0  4.0  1.0  0.0  512.0  343.0  216.0  125.0  64.0  27.0  8.0  1.0  0.0  4096.0  2401.0  1296.0  625.0  256.0  81.0  16.0  1.0  0.0  32768.0  16807.0  7776.0  3125.0  1024.0  243.0  32.0  1.0  0.0


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Sample data
data = {
    '1': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    '2': [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81],
    '3': [0, 1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216, 343, 512, 729],
    '4': [0, 1, 16, 81, 256, 625, 1296, 2401, 4096, 6561],
    '5': [0, 1, 32, 243, 1024, 3125, 7776, 16807, 32768, 59049]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

shift_range = 8 

shifted_dfs = [df.shift(i).add_suffix(f'-{i}') for i in range(1, shift_range +1 )]

concatenated = pd.concat(shifted_dfs,axis=1)
print(concatenated.to_string())
"""
   1-1   2-1    3-1     4-1      5-1  1-2   2-2    3-2     4-2      5-2  1-3   2-3    3-3     4-3     5-3  1-4   2-4    3-4    4-4     5-4  1-5   2-5   3-5    4-5     5-5  1-6  2-6   3-6   4-6    5-6  1-7  2-7  3-7   4-7   5-7  1-8  2-8  3-8  4-8  5-8
0  NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN      NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN      NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  0.0   0.0    0.0     0.0      0.0  NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN      NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  1.0   1.0    1.0     1.0      1.0  0.0   0.0    0.0     0.0      0.0  NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  2.0   4.0    8.0    16.0     32.0  1.0   1.0    1.0     1.0      1.0  0.0   0.0    0.0     0.0     0.0  NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  3.0   9.0   27.0    81.0    243.0  2.0   4.0    8.0    16.0     32.0  1.0   1.0    1.0     1.0     1.0  0.0   0.0    0.0    0.0     0.0  NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5  4.0  16.0   64.0   256.0   1024.0  3.0   9.0   27.0    81.0    243.0  2.0   4.0    8.0    16.0    32.0  1.0   1.0    1.0    1.0     1.0  0.0   0.0   0.0    0.0     0.0  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
6  5.0  25.0  125.0   625.0   3125.0  4.0  16.0   64.0   256.0   1024.0  3.0   9.0   27.0    81.0   243.0  2.0   4.0    8.0   16.0    32.0  1.0   1.0   1.0    1.0     1.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0    0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7  6.0  36.0  216.0  1296.0   7776.0  5.0  25.0  125.0   625.0   3125.0  4.0  16.0   64.0   256.0  1024.0  3.0   9.0   27.0   81.0   243.0  2.0   4.0   8.0   16.0    32.0  1.0  1.0   1.0   1.0    1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
8  7.0  49.0  343.0  2401.0  16807.0  6.0  36.0  216.0  1296.0   7776.0  5.0  25.0  125.0   625.0  3125.0  4.0  16.0   64.0  256.0  1024.0  3.0   9.0  27.0   81.0   243.0  2.0  4.0   8.0  16.0   32.0  1.0  1.0  1.0   1.0   1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
9  8.0  64.0  512.0  4096.0  32768.0  7.0  49.0  343.0  2401.0  16807.0  6.0  36.0  216.0  1296.0  7776.0  5.0  25.0  125.0  625.0  3125.0  4.0  16.0  64.0  256.0  1024.0  3.0  9.0  27.0  81.0  243.0  2.0  4.0  8.0  16.0  32.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
"""

